# Junit at private methods

Tags: java, junit, private

I am doing a JUnit test of a class and I needed to add two methods in the class that read the encrypted password+salt of the object. I only want to use them for this, can I somehow make them private, but still call them in the test?
For example:

```
private String getPassForTest(){
return this.encryptedPass
}
```

Then in my test I would like to access it

```
User tester = new User();
PreparedStatement actual = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `Password`) VALUES ('"tester.getEncryptedForTest() +"')";
```

Comment: Don't directly (unit) test private methods. Test them by testing the (non-private) methods that use them. If there aren't any such, then you can delete the private method.

Answer (score 0):

If your test class is in the "mirror package" of test, instead of declaring the method as private you could use protected or package scope.

This is a common practice, specially if you signal/comment the method with "visible only for test".

Comment: this is bad advice, private methods are private because they are not to be used elsewhere. making them protected makes them open for all subclasses and all classes in the same package. This might be a deal changer.